# Negative lookbehind on html comments with PHP for script extraction

Tags: php, html, regex, internet-explorer

I have a bit of a problem with IE comments in HTML.
I'm trying to parse scripts from an html string, which is not very hard.
But, in my regular expression, i'm catching IE commented scripts, and I don't really want that.

Currently my script is :

```
function get_scripts($html){

   preg_match_all('#<script(.*?)</script>#is', $html, $matches);

   $scripts = "";

   if(isset($matches[0]) && is_array($matches[0])){   
      foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
          $scripts .= $value;
      } 
   }

    return $scripts;
   }


  $html = ' 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var domain_blog_json="";
    </script>
 ';

 echo get_scripts($html);
```

Does anyone knows how to achieve this ?
I've tryed negative lookbehind but it doesn't work, or I am (certainly) a noob in Reg Exp.

Thanks !

Comment: Dont use REGEX for html parsing. Use a proper html parser like DomDocument. That will ignore conditional comments by default

Comment: Yep i know, but i like to do it the hard way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!--.*?-->|<script(.*?)<\/script>
```

Try this.Grab the capture.It will only give `scripts` from non commented section.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/20

Comment: Last issue : it catches 
     <!--[if lt IE 9]> <p> <label for="bla">Blabla</label> </p> <![endif]-->

Any idea ?

Comment: Nope, only script tags without comments :)
I've done a workaround, i do a preg_replace for comments when i do the loop. It works, so that's ok :).

Answer (score 1):

You've asked for a regular expression here, but it's not the right tool for parsing HTML. You can utilize [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to perform this task which is preferable instead of trying to reinvent the wheel by using a regular expression.

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
   var domain_blog_json="";
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
');

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('script') as $n) {
   echo $doc->saveHTML($n);
}
```

Output

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var domain_blog_json="";
</script>
```

Comment: In fact, i'm assuming i can't use DOMDocument, for compatibility reasons. Yes it's odd. But your solution is ok :).

Answer (score 0):

Check your regular expression, see [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_preg_match_all.htm), And I think you can modify your expression to something like this :

```
      '/<script>(.*)<\/script>/U'
```

Untested thou. but I think that should fix you regex expression.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, as it captures only what is in-between non-IE `<script>` tags. A look behind isn't really necessary for this unless you're wanting to capture both groups at once or do something special in-particular.

```
(<script.+[\n<][^!][^><\/]+\n.+>)
```

**Example:**

**http://regex101.com/r/mL2gU0/3**

---

<sub>If you wanted to capture the IE tags you could use: `(<!--\[.+IE.+[\n<].+[^!][^><\/].+)` [[example]](http://regex101.com/r/pH7cN1/1)</sub>